# compress uploaded image if too big

Tags: php, compression

So I am trying to adjust my image uploader so that if an image is over 35kb compress it, but it doesn't seem to work, don't think i'm doing it right as it always gives me the error
"File size too big! The max is 35kb, try to use some more compression on it, or find another image."

Here's my code:

```
function article_top_image($article_id)
{
    global $db, $config;

    if (isset($_FILES['new_image']) && $_FILES['new_image']['error'] == 0)
    {
        if (!@fopen($_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'], 'r'))
        {
            $this->error_message = "Could not find image, did you select one to upload?";
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            // check the dimensions
            list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name']);

            // check if its too big
            if ($_FILES['new_image']['size'] > 35900)
            {
                // compress it to see if we can make it smaller
                imagejpeg($_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'], 50);

                // check again
                if ($_FILES['new_image']['size'] > 35900)
                {
                    $this->error_message = 'File size too big! The max is 35kb, try to use some more compression on it, or find another image.';
                    return false;
                }
            }

            else if ($width > $config['article_image_max_width'] || $height > $config['article_image_max_height'])
            {
                $this->error_message = 'Too big!';
                return false;
            }

            // this will make sure it is an image file, if it cant get an image size then its not an image
            else if (!getimagesize($_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name']))
            {
                $this->error_message = 'Not an image!';
                return false;
            }   
        }

        // see if they currently have an avatar set
        $db->sqlquery("SELECT `article_top_image` FROM `articles` WHERE `article_id` = ?", array($article_id));
        $image = $db->fetch();

        // give the image a random file name
        $imagename = rand() . 'id' . $article_id . '.jpg';

        // the actual image
        $source = $_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'];

        // where to upload to
        $target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/articles/topimages/" . $imagename;  

        if (move_uploaded_file($source, $target))
        {           
            // remove old avatar
            if ($image['article_top_image'] == 1)
            {
                unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/articles/topimages/' . $image['article_top_image_filename']);
            }

            $db->sqlquery("UPDATE `articles` SET `article_top_image` = 1, `article_top_image_filename` = ? WHERE `article_id` = ?", array($imagename, $article_id));
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            $this->error_message = 'Could not upload file!';
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Somehow I don't think `$_FILES['new_image']['size']` will be magically updated with the new image size after you resave that image. Aside from that, it's not necessarily guaranteed that an image can be compressed to 35 KB in one pass without losing too much quality.

Comment: Quality isn't much of an issue since it will be a really small image.

Answer (score 1):

you have to reuse `filesize`. It may be necessary to call first `clearstatcache`.

```
filesize($_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'])
```

Comment: Doing clearstatcache and then doing if (filesize($_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name']) > 35900) still results in the same error everytime

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on compressing images which are big. I am using the following code.

```
function image_quality()
{
    $name = ''; $type = ''; $size = ''; $error = '';
    function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality)
    {
        $info = getimagesize($source_url);

            if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
                    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);

            elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
                    $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);

            elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
                    $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);

            imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
        return $destination_url;
    }

    $dir   = 'images_high';
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach($files as $image)
    {   
        $size=filesize("images_high/$image");
        if ($size <=50000)
                rename("images_high/$image","user_images/$image");

        $url = "user_images/$image";
        $filename = compress_image("images_high/$image", $url, 20);
        $buffer = file_get_contents($url);

        unlink("images_high/$image");
    }
}
```

I hope It will help you.